# Live Display inventory for Paypal button

Tags: web, paypal, inventory

I am trying to integrate a PayPal buy button into my website, and I am using the built-in inventory feature. I am trying to find a way to display how many units are left for inventory, as it will be small group tickets I am selling and I want my customers to know if an event is full or not. how would I display that?

Answer (score 0):

The basic HTML hosted buttons generated by PayPal will not display remaining inventory.

To do so, essentially you need your own database that tracks inventory and displays this value on page load. When processing a transaction, before capturing a payment you should verify that there is enough remaining inventory, and decrement the inventory when the capture is successful.

There are third party solutions that implement such functionality (stock/inventory management), if you are unfamiliar with how to program such a site your self. PayPal's [partner directory](https://www.paypal.com/us/business/platforms-and-marketplaces/directory) may be a place to start, and you can also search the web.